# How make np.argsort place empty strings at the END of an array instead of at the beginning

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, is-empty

I'm honestly surprised that this question hasn't come up on the forums (at least from what I have seen) earlier. Anyway, I am currently attempting to sort a list of strings, many of which are empty, in alphabetic fashion using np.argsort like so:

```
list = [ "Carrot", "Star", "Beta", "Zoro" , ""]
```

Right now, any call of np.argsort(list) will return the following array of indices:

```
[4,2,0,1,3] # => ["", "Beta", "Carrot", "Star", "Zoro"]
```

Is there a way to specify the order of the argsort function so that the empty strings are placed at the end of the array like so:

```
[2,0,1,3,4] # => ["Beta", "Carrot", "Star", "Zoro", ""]
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way of getting the order you want would be using `np.roll`:

```
lst = [ "Carrot", "Star", "Beta", "Zoro" , ""]
arr = np.array(lst)
idx = np.roll(arr.argsort(),np.count_nonzero(arr))
arr[idx]
# array(['Beta', 'Carrot', 'Star', 'Zoro', ''], dtype='<U6')
```

Comment: Superb answer. Worked like a charm. Would you mind walking me through (as best you can) what you are doing with this line?
``` 
idx = np.roll(arr.argsort(),np.count_nonzero(arr)) 

```
I'm not familiar with the roll command.

Comment: @Caladin00 `np.roll(a,n)` takes the last `n` elements of `a` and moves them to the front. `np.count_nonzero` in this case counts the number of strings that are not empty. `argsort` has put their indices to the end, we use `np.roll`  to move them to the start.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use *Numpy* methods, use them on *Numpy* arrays, not on
"ordinary" *Python* lists.

So start from generating a *Numpy* array, for demonstration purpose,
extended a little:

```
list = [ "Carrot", "Star", "Beta", "None", "none", "Zoro" , "", "zzz"]
lst = np.array(list)
```

Then:

- change each empty string in *lst* or e.g. *none* / *None* with
  a *tilde* (the last char in ASCII),
- apply *argsort* to it (instead of the original array).

The code to do it is:

```
np.argsort(np.where(~np.isin(lst, ['', 'None', 'none']), lst, '~'))
```

which gives:

```
array([2, 0, 1, 5, 7, 3, 4, 6], dtype=int64)
```

so indices concerning:

- *"None"* (index == *3*),
- *"none"* (index == *4*),
- *""* (empty string, index == *6*)

are at the end, but e.g. the index *7* concerning *"zzz"* is before them.

Comment: Does this work if the list includes strings like 'none' and 'zzz'?

Comment: In these cases both *none* and *zzz* are normal strings and will be sorted according to its content. But consider changing to *np.nan* also such strings like e.g. *none*.

Comment: My point is that the `where` inserts the string "nan" in the new array, not the float `np.nan`.  This example only works because all the other strings start with upper case, which sorts before lower.

Comment: Don't be misleaded by *'nan'* string in the printout.
It is only a **text representation** of *np.nan*.

Comment: what's the dtype of the array?